# How do i add dashed polyline in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, xcode9

i already have a polyline in Swift4, how can i make the style of it to Dashed/Dotted line ??

```
  let   path = GMSMutablePath(path: GMSPath())
    for marker in markerList {
        bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(marker.position)
        path.add(marker.position)

    }



    let polyline = GMSPolyline(path: path)
    polyline.strokeColor = UIColor(named: "Primary")!
    polyline.strokeWidth = 3.0
    polyline.geodesic = true
    polyline.map = mapView
```

[Like this map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3xfv.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to implement `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer` delegate method and using `renderer.lineDashPhase` and `renderer.lineDashPattern` properties you should be able to achive what you need

**code example**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.red
    renderer.lineWidth = 4.0
    renderer.lineDashPhase = 2
    renderer.lineDashPattern = [NSNumber(value: 1),NSNumber(value:5)]
    return renderer
}
```

**result**

[image]